# Showing the interior derivative of a differential form satisfies certain properties

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

I'm quite new to differential forms/interior derivatives so if anyone could help with understanding the intuition behind proving this certain property step by step would be great.

Let $\iota_X$ denote the interior derivative of differential forms with a vector field $X$. Show that the operator: $$L_X:= \iota_X \ \circ d \ + \ d \ \circ \ \iota_X$$

satisfies $$L_X(\omega_1 \ \wedge \ \omega_2)=(L_X \omega_1) \ \wedge \omega_2 \ + \ \omega_1 \ \wedge \ (L_X \omega_2)$$

So far I have gotten to the expression:

$$\iota_X \ \circ \ [(d\omega_1) \ \wedge \ \omega_2 \ + \ (-1)^k\omega_1 \ \wedge \ d(\omega_2)] \ + d \ \circ \ [(\iota_X\omega_1) \ \wedge \ \omega_2 \ + \ (-1)^k\omega_1 \ \wedge \iota_X(\omega_2)]$$

by using the following properties:

$$\text{(1)} \ \ \ d(\omega_1 \wedge \omega_2)=d\omega_1 \wedge \omega_2 +(-1)^k(\omega_1 \wedge d\omega_2)$$

$$\text{(2)} \ \ \ \iota_X(\omega_1 \wedge \omega_2) = \iota_X(\omega_1) \wedge \omega_2 + (-1)^k\omega_1 \wedge \iota_X(\omega_2)$$

Edit: after substituting the properties again for a second time I am left with:

$$\iota_x \ \circ \ d\omega_1 \ \wedge \ \omega_2 \ + \ (-1)^k d\omega_1 \ \wedge \ \iota_x(\omega_2)  \ + \ (-1)^k \iota_x \omega_1 \ \wedge d\omega_2 \ + \ (-1)^{2k} \omega_1 \ \wedge \ (\iota_X \ \circ \ d\omega_2) \ + \ d \ \circ \ \iota_X \omega_1 \ \wedge \ \omega_2 \ + \ (-1)^k(\iota_X \omega_1 \ \wedge \ d\omega_2) \ + \ (-1)^k(d\omega_1) \ \wedge \ \iota_X \omega_2 \ + \ (-1)^{2k}\omega_1 \ \wedge \ (d \ \circ \ \iota_x\omega_2)$$

Comment: Have you written down the right-hand side? How do the terms compare?

Comment: Yes I have, but I'm unsure how to get rid of the (-1)^k parts etc

Comment: What do you mean “get rid of”? What you’ve written down so far expands to 8 terms. Do they simplify/combine to give the 4 terms on the right-hand side? Write it all out explicitly.

Comment: Ah I've been expanding it wrong, I thought it expanded to give 4 terms. I'm still very new to this topic. how do we get the extra 4?

Comment: Your two formulas below show you how each type of term turns into two!

Comment: oh right so... for example, the part where i have $[(\iota_X\omega_1) \wedge \omega_2 ...$ I can use property (2) again?

Comment: No, you already used property (2) to get this. But you need to compute $d(\dots)$ here, so use property (1). In the first term, you need to use (2) again, right?

Comment: Oh right! so just to clarify, i'll be computing in the first term $\iota_X [(d\omega_1) \wedge \omega_2]+...$ by using the second property?

Comment: Looks right to me! Don't psyche yourself out on this. Just apply the relevant rules when they apply!

Comment: Ok, I managed to get 99% of the way there. So I just checked my answers and I should be getting $\iota_X \circ d\omega_1 \wedge_2 + (-1)^{k+1}d\omega_1 \wedge \iota_x (\omega_2)$ but I'm getting a $(-1)^k$ on the second term not a $(-1)^{k+1}$, I can't see what I'm doing wrong

Comment: If you want to edit your post to include the details of your computation, I will look, but I can’t just guess what’s going on. Did 4 of the terms cancel out?

Comment: I'll do that now :)

Comment: Assuming you're going in order, the second term has a sign error. You're moving $\iota_X$ across $d\omega_1$, which is now a $(k+1)$-form. You have a similar error later on when you move $d$ across $\iota_X\omega_1$, which is now a $(k-1)$-form. If you check all these things carefully, you should have it.

Comment: oh right and that would mean when i move $d$ across $\iota_X \omega_1$ i'll get a $(k-1)$-form? 

Just saw the edit: thank you so much for your time and help!:)

Comment: You're welcome. Why don't you post a complete answer when you're done? I'll upvote you :)

Comment: Good job, you two

Answer (score 4):

Following from above:

\begin{align} 
L_X(\omega_1 \wedge \omega_2) &= (\iota_X \circ d + d \circ \iota_X)(\omega_1 \wedge \omega_2) = (\iota_X \circ d)(\omega_1 \wedge \omega_2)+ (d \circ \iota_X)(\omega_1 \wedge \omega_2)\\ 
&= \iota_X \circ [(d\omega_1) \wedge \omega_2 + (-1)^k\omega_1 \wedge d(\omega_2)]+ d\circ [(\iota_X \omega_1) \wedge \omega_2+(-1)^k\omega_1 \wedge\iota_X(\omega_2)]\\ 
&= \iota_X \circ d\omega_1  \wedge \omega_2 + (-1)^{k+1} d\omega_1 \wedge \iota_X\omega_2 + (-1)^k \iota_X \omega_1 \wedge d\omega_2 + (-1)^{2k} \omega_1 \wedge \iota_X \circ d\omega_2 \\ & \qquad + d\circ\iota_X \omega_1 \wedge \omega_2  +  (-1)^{k-1}\iota_X \omega_1 \wedge d\omega_2 + (-1)^k d\omega_1 \wedge \iota_X \omega_2 + (-1)^{2k}\omega_1 \wedge d\circ\iota_X\omega_2\\ 
&= (\iota_X \circ d\omega_1 \wedge \omega_2  + d\circ \iota_X\omega_1 \wedge \omega_2) + (\omega_1 \wedge \iota_X \circ d\omega_2 + \omega_1 \wedge d\circ \iota_X \omega_2)\\
&= (L_X\omega_1) \wedge \omega_2 + \omega_1 \wedge (L_X \omega_2)\\ 
\end{align}

Thank you for the help Ted!:)